# Setting NSArray to nil under ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I added some logging to all of my `init`s and `dealloc`s to try to understand why my ARC-enabled project was consuming more and more memory as runtime continued. I found that one view controller was responsible. It's main duty at initialization is to create an `NSMutableArray` and fill it with `NSNull` objects. During execution, it swaps out these null objects for more meaningful objects, and vice versa - a basic lazy loading setup.

When this view controller is popped, any non-null views that are in the `NSMutableArray` at that time are not released. As a result, the view controller itself is also not released.

I can resolve this by either emptying the `NSMutableArray` or setting it to nil.

What makes this necessary? Is it always my responsibility to set an array to nil if I created it, even under ARC? Or must something else be retaining one of the objects in the array, and preventing it from automatically deallocating?

Comment: Assuming the `NSMutableArray` is an instance variable (not a global), it should be released when the view controller is released. Have you confirmed that the view controller itself is being released (e.g. breakpoint or `NSLog` in `dealloc`). Just because you pop doesn't mean it's been released, such as if you're suffering from strong reference cycle (aka retain cycle).

Comment: Well I noticed that if the array gets initialized, but never filled (ie it only contains null objects at the time of the pop) the view controller gets released just fine. I confirmed this by logging in `dealloc`. Is that of any help?

Comment: Go ahead and fill it up again and see if, when you pop, whether `dealloc` is called. Because if it is, your instance variables should be released. If `dealloc` isn't getting called, then it's probably a strong reference cycle (e.g. if the view controller itself referenced in this `NSMutableArray`, that would result in a strong reference cycle).

Comment: The view controller isn't deallocated if there is anything other than null in its array. So am I looking at this backwards? I assumed that the reason the view controller wasn't deallocated was because there was something in the array that prevented it. Instead, are you saying that the opposite is true - ie the view controller isn't being deallocated, so the array is never released? But if this is the case, why would the contents of the array affect whether or not the view controller is deallocated on release?

Comment: Ah - if something IN the array is what's keeping the view controller from being deallocated, right?

Comment: Correct. Your controller won't be deallocated until there are zero references to it. Generally, when you pop, that's the last reference and it gets deallocated. But if you have a `NSMutableArray`, for example, that has a strong reference to the controller itself, then you end up with circular references, e.g. [strong reference cycles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW22).

Comment: I replaced the reference with delegation - it was lazy not to do so in the first place. All is well. Many thanks. Feel free to write this up as an answer, or else I will do so later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `NSMutableArray` is an instance variable, it should be released when the view controller is released. If your controller's `dealloc` is getting called when the `NSMutableArray` only has `NSNull` objects, but it's not getting deallocated when you fill your array with "meaningful" content, that means that you undoubtedly have a [strong reference cycle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW22), i.e. there must be some reference to the view controller, itself, in the contents of the `NSMutableArray`.